# PHP array Encoding and Decoding:Need a function for encoding and decoding string or array with delimiters or array itself

Tags: php, arrays, encoding, decoding

I am in a need of function that will encode and decode all the id's of a tree nodes.
I function that will check if its a single string or array string or string with delimiters.
I am having one plugin for encoding and decoding.
here goes my plugin:

**FIle:encode.class.php**

```
<?php

/*-------------------------
Author: Jonathan Pulice
Date: July 26th, 2005
Name: JPEncodeClass v1
Desc: Encoder and decoder using patterns.
-------------------------*/

class Protector
{

    var $Pattern = "";
    var $PatternFlip = "";
    var $ToEncode = "";
    var $ToDecode = "";
    var $Decoded = "";
    var $Encoded = "";
    var $Bug = false;
    var $DecodePattern = "";

    function Debug($on = true)
    {
        $this->Bug = $on;
    }

    function Encode()
    {


        $ar = explode(":", $this->Pattern);
        $enc = $this->ToEncode;

        if ($this->Bug) echo "<!-- BEGIN ENCODING -->\n";

        foreach ($ar as $num => $ltr)
        {   
            switch ($ltr)
            {
                case "E":
                    $enc = base64_encode($enc);
                    break;
                case "D":
                    $enc = base64_decode($enc);
                    break;
                case "R":
                    $enc = strrev($enc);
                    break;
                case "I":
                    $enc = $this->InvertCase($enc);
                    break;
            }
            if ($this->Bug) echo "<!--     {$ltr}: {$enc}  -->\n";
        }

        if ($this->Bug) echo "<!-------------------->\n\n";

        @$this->Encoded = ($enc == $this->Str) ? "<font color='red'>No Encoding/Decoding Pattern Detected!</font>" : $enc;

        return $this->Encoded;

    }

    function Decode()
    {

        $pattern = ($this->DecodePattern != "") ? $this->DecodePattern : $this->Pattern;

        //Reverse the pattern
        $this->PatternFlip($pattern);

        //make into an array
        $ar = explode(":", $this->PatternFlip);

        $t = ($this->Encoded == "") ? $this->ToDecode : $this->Encoded;

        if ($this->Bug) echo "<!-- BEGIN DECODING -->\n";

        foreach ($ar as $num => $ltr)
        {
            switch ($ltr)
            {
                case "E":
                    $t = base64_encode($t);
                    break;
                case "D":
                    $t = base64_decode($t);
                    break;
                case "R":
                    $t = strrev($t);
                    break;
                case "I":
                    $t = $this->InvertCase($t);
                    break;
            }
            if ($this->Bug) echo "<!--     {$ltr}: {$t}  -->\n";
        }

        if ($this->Bug) echo "<!-------------------->\n\n";

        $this->Decoded = ($t == $this->Encoded) ? "<font color='red'>No Encoding/Decoding Pattern Detected!</font>" : $t;

        return $this->Decoded;

    }

    function MakePattern($len = 10)
    {
        //possible letters
        // E - Base64 Encode
        // R - Reverse String
        // I - Inverse Case
        $poss = array('E','R', 'I');

        //generate a string
        for ( $i = 0 ; $i < $len ; $i++ )
        {
            $tmp[] = $poss[ rand(0,2) ];
        }

        //echo $str. "<br>";
        //fix useless pattern section  RR  II
        $str = implode(":", $tmp);

        //fix
        $str = str_replace( 'R:R:R:R:R:R' , 'R:E:R:E:R:E' , $str );
        $str = str_replace( 'R:R:R:R:R' , 'R:E:R:E:R' , $str );
        $str = str_replace( 'R:R:R:R' , 'R:E:R:E' , $str );
        $str = str_replace( 'R:R:R' , 'R:E:R' , $str );
        $str = str_replace( 'R:R' , 'R:E' , $str );

        //fix
        $str = str_replace( 'I:I:I:I:I:I' , 'I:E:I:E:I:E' , $str );
        $str = str_replace( 'I:I:I:I:I' , 'I:E:I:E:I' , $str );
        $str = str_replace( 'I:I:I:I' , 'I:E:I:E' , $str );
        $str = str_replace( 'I:I:I' , 'I:E:I' , $str );
        $str = str_replace( 'I:I' , 'I:E' , $str );

        //string is good, set as pattern
        $this->Pattern = $str;
        return $this->Pattern; //if we need it

    }

    function PatternFlip($pattern)
    {
        //reverse the pattern
        $str = strrev($pattern);

        $ar = explode(":", $str);

        foreach ($ar as $num => $ltr)
        {   
            switch ($ltr)
            {
                case "E":
                    $tmp[] = "D";
                    break;
                case "D":
                    $tmp[] = "E";
                    break;
                case "R":
                    $tmp[] = "R";
                    break;
                case "I":
                    $tmp[] = "I";
                    break;
            }

        }

        $rev = implode(":", $tmp);

        $this->PatternFlip = $rev;

        return $this->PatternFlip;
    }

    // This is my custom Case Invertor!
    //   if you would like to use this in a script, please credit it to me, thank you
    function InvertCase($str)
    {
        //Do initial conversion
        $new = strtoupper( $str );

        //spluit into arrays
        $s = str_split( $str );
        $n = str_split( $new );

        //now we step through each letter, and if its the same as before, we swap it out
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($s); $i++)
        {
            if ( $s[$i] === $n[$i] ) //SWAP THE LETTER
            {
                //ge the letter
                $num = ord( $n[$i] );

                //see if the ord is in the alpha ranges ( 65 - 90 | 97 - 122 )
                if ( ( $num >= 65 AND $num <= 90 ) OR ( $num >= 97 AND $num <= 122 ) )
                {
                    if ($num < 97 ) { $num = $num + 32; }
                    else { $num = $num - 32; }

                    $newchr = chr($num);

                    $n[$i] = $newchr;
                }
            }
        }

        //join the new string back together
        $newstr = implode("", $n);

        return $newstr;

    }

}

?>
```

By using the functions from this plugin I have to write a function to check for different conditions.

Comment: Please tell us exactly what you are trying to accomplish.  "check for different conditions" is too vague of a goal for us to help you.

Comment: ya i am having a tree where i am listing categories and sub categories.... i need to check for different conditions for encoding and decoding the id's that will go to the front end........here i need to check for single string,array of strings,string with delimiters......

Comment: You keep saying you need to check for conditions.  What conditions?  What dictates them?  What controls them?  What kind of encoding are you talking about?  What is your actual end goal?  What are you building?  All we've got right now is that *horrible* data obfuscation code and no clear idea of what you want to do with it.

Comment: sorry....i need to create 2 functions.......
1->encode
2->decode

..............

I am working on a module where i am listing all the categories and subcategories in a tree structure.
In front end all the id's of the categories and sub categories will come,which i want to encode and while retrieving back i want id's to be decoded..........

so in my functions i want to check for conditions,
1) array of id's(multidimensional array for specific keys)
2) single variable or variables with set of delimiters having multiple id's.........
3)using loop i need to check for these conditions...........

Answer (score 0):

I wrote you a prototype for an extended class from this base class. Not sure what `$PatternFlip` is for, its not accessible in this class  so you'll have to change it as you see necessary. If you want the result in a different format you can add functions to the class.

```
class MyProtector extends Protector {

var $Object;
var $encode;//1 means encode, not 1 means decode
var $result;

function __MyProtector($obj="",$encode=0,$pattern="") {
   $this->$Object=$obj;
   if($encode){//encode object
       $this->$EncodePattern=$pattern;
       $this->$result=smartEncode($obj);
   }else{//decode object
       $this->$DecodePattern=$pattern;
       $this->result=smartDecode($obj);
}
}

private function smartEncode($object){
   //encodes string or array
   if(is_array($object){
       return encodeArray($object);
   }else if(is_string($object)){
       return encodeString($object);
   }

   return 0;

}

private function smartDecode($object){
   //encodes string or array
   if(is_string($object)&&strpos("&",$object)===1){
       return encodeDelimiter($object);
   }else if(is_string($object)){
       return encodeString($object);
   }

   return 0;

}
private function decodeDelimiter($object){
   $a=explode("&",$string);//will only work if your encoding does not include "&"!
   $aDecoded=array();
   $k=0; 
   foreach($a as $i){
     $this->toDecode=$i;
     $aDecoded[$k]=$this->Decode();
     $k++;          
   }
   return $aDecoded;


}

private function decodeString($s){
$this->toDecode=$s;
    return $this->Decode();
}

private function encodeString($s){
   $this->toEncode=$s;
   return $this->Encode();
}

private function encodeArray($s){
   foreach($s as $i){
  $this->toEncode=$i;
      $s=$s.$this->Encode()."&";
   }
   return $s;
}
//setters and getters
function getPattern(){
   return $this->Pattern;
}

function getPatternFlip(){
    return $this->Pattern;
}   
function getPattern(){
    return $this->Pattern;
}

//..etc
```

Example usage:

```
$o=new MyProtector($string,0,$pattern);
echo $o->$result; //returns encoded string
$o=new MyProtector($string,1,$pattern);
echo $o->$result; //returns decoded string
$o=new MyProtector($array,0,$pattern);
echo $o->$result; //returns decoded string with '&' inbetween encoded array entries
$o=new MyProtector($stringWithDelimiter,1,$pattern);
echo $o->$result;//returns decoded array
```

I'm sure there will be a few syntax errors, typos in there as I haven't compiled/tried the thing. Hope that helped.