# how to encode and decode multidimensional arrays in php?

Tags: php, arrays, encoding, decoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP array Encoding and Decoding:Need a function for encoding and decoding string or array with delimiters or array itself…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322129/php-array-encoding-and-decodingneed-a-function-for-encoding-and-decoding-string)

hi.
i am new to php.
i need to write two separate functions for encoding and decoding of multidimensional arrays in php.
i have attached one plugin ..........
encode.class.php..............

```
<?php

/*-------------------------
Author: Jonathan Pulice
Date: July 26th, 2005
Name: JPEncodeClass v1
Desc: Encoder and decoder using patterns.
-------------------------*/

class Protector
{

    var $Pattern = "";
    var $PatternFlip = "";
    var $ToEncode = "";
    var $ToDecode = "";
    var $Decoded = "";
    var $Encoded = "";
    var $Bug = false;
    var $DecodePattern = "";

    function Debug($on = true)
    {
        $this->Bug = $on;
    }

    function Encode()
    {


        $ar = explode(":", $this->Pattern);
        $enc = $this->ToEncode;

        if ($this->Bug) echo "<!-- BEGIN ENCODING -->\n";

        foreach ($ar as $num => $ltr)
        {
            switch ($ltr)
            {
                case "E":
                $enc = base64_encode($enc);
                break;
                case "D":
                $enc = base64_decode($enc);
                break;
                case "R":
                $enc = strrev($enc);
                break;
                case "I":
                $enc = $this->InvertCase($enc);
                break;
            }
            if ($this->Bug) echo "<!-- {$ltr}: {$enc} -->\n";
        }

        if ($this->Bug) echo "<!-------------------->\n\n";

        @$this->Encoded = ($enc == $this->Str) ? "<font color='red'>No Encoding/Decoding Pattern Detected!</font>" : $enc;

        return $this->Encoded;

    }

    function Decode()
    {

        $pattern = ($this->DecodePattern != "") ? $this->DecodePattern : $this->Pattern;

        //Reverse the pattern
        $this->PatternFlip($pattern);

        //make into an array
        $ar = explode(":", $this->PatternFlip);

        $t = ($this->Encoded == "") ? $this->ToDecode : $this->Encoded;

        if ($this->Bug) echo "<!-- BEGIN DECODING -->\n";

        foreach ($ar as $num => $ltr)
        {
        switch ($ltr)
        {
            case "E":
            $t = base64_encode($t);
            break;
            case "D":
            $t = base64_decode($t);
            break;
            case "R":
            $t = strrev($t);
            break;
            case "I":
            $t = $this->InvertCase($t);
            break;
            }
            if ($this->Bug) echo "<!-- {$ltr}: {$t} -->\n";
        }

        if ($this->Bug) echo "<!-------------------->\n\n";

        $this->Decoded = ($t == $this->Encoded) ? "<font color='red'>No Encoding/Decoding Pattern Detected!</font>" : $t;

        return $this->Decoded;

    }

    function MakePattern($len = 10)
    {
        //possible letters
        // E - Base64 Encode
        // R - Reverse String
        // I - Inverse Case
        $poss = array('E','R', 'I');

        //generate a string
        for ( $i = 0 ; $i < $len ; $i++ )
        {
            $tmp[] = $poss[ rand(0,2) ];
        }

        //echo $str. "<br>";
        //fix useless pattern section RR II
        $str = implode(":", $tmp);

        //fix
        $str = str_replace( 'R:R:R:R:R:R' , 'R:E:R:E:R:E' , $str );
        $str = str_replace( 'R:R:R:R:R' , 'R:E:R:E:R' , $str );
        $str = str_replace( 'R:R:R:R' , 'R:E:R:E' , $str );
        $str = str_replace( 'R:R:R' , 'R:E:R' , $str );
        $str = str_replace( 'R:R' , 'R:E' , $str );

        //fix
        $str = str_replace( 'I:I:I:I:I:I' , 'I:E:I:E:I:E' , $str );
        $str = str_replace( 'I:I:I:I:I' , 'I:E:I:E:I' , $str );
        $str = str_replace( 'I:I:I:I' , 'I:E:I:E' , $str );
        $str = str_replace( 'I:I:I' , 'I:E:I' , $str );
        $str = str_replace( 'I:I' , 'I:E' , $str );

        //string is good, set as pattern
        $this->Pattern = $str;
        return $this->Pattern; //if we need it

    }

    function PatternFlip($pattern)
    {
        //reverse the pattern
        $str = strrev($pattern);

        $ar = explode(":", $str);

        foreach ($ar as $num => $ltr)
        {
            switch ($ltr)
            {
                case "E":
                $tmp[] = "D";
                break;
                case "D":
                $tmp[] = "E";
                break;
                case "R":
                $tmp[] = "R";
                break;
                case "I":
                $tmp[] = "I";
                break;
            }

        }

        $rev = implode(":", $tmp);

        $this->PatternFlip = $rev;

        return $this->PatternFlip;
    }

    // This is my custom Case Invertor!
    // if you would like to use this in a script, please credit it to me, thank you
    function InvertCase($str)
    {
        //Do initial conversion
        $new = strtoupper( $str );

        //spluit into arrays
        $s = str_split( $str );
        $n = str_split( $new );

        //now we step through each letter, and if its the same as before, we swap it out
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($s); $i++)
        {
            if ( $s[$i] === $n[$i] ) //SWAP THE LETTER
            {
                //ge the letter
                $num = ord( $n[$i] );

                //see if the ord is in the alpha ranges ( 65 - 90 | 97 - 122 )
                if ( ( $num >= 65 AND $num <= 90 ) OR ( $num >= 97 AND $num <= 122 ) )
                {
                    if ($num < 97 ) { $num = $num + 32; }
                    else { $num = $num - 32; }

                    $newchr = chr($num);

                    $n[$i] = $newchr;
                }
            }
        }

        //join the new string back together
        $newstr = implode("", $n);

        return $newstr;

    }

}

?>............
```

from this plugin i need to use the encode and decode functions in my functions for pattern checking.
If anybody can help me.......It ll be good for me.coz i am in need of it........

Comment: [How is this different from your previous question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322129/php-array-encoding-and-decodingneed-a-function-for-encoding-and-decoding-string)  Seems like an exact duplicate to me, right down to the less-than-useful explanation.

Comment: To get this right: you have the algorithm for encoding but it works only on a regular array and you want to be able to encode trees actually (n-dimensional arrays)?

Comment: Your question is not answerable, because it is not a question. It's an request to have something coded for your. Since you do not explain the confusing code or what you are trying to do in any meaningful way, there won't be anyone who can help you. Posting it again under a new user account won't change that. So please leave it.

Comment: ya Catalin you are right.....it works for single array but for tree structure its not working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322129/php-array-encoding-and-decodingneed-a-function-for-encoding-and-decoding-string I answered your question in the original post.

Answer (score 9):

Use [`serialize()`](http://php.net/serialize) and [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/unserialize) to turn the arrays into strings and back into arrays (also works with everything else except resources)

Answer (score 1):

seems like a pretty large encoder/decoder class.

maybe this RC4 algorithm would be easier

```
//encrypt
$encrypted = RC4Crypt::encrypt('your key','some string to encrypt');

//decrypt
$decrypted = RC4Crypt::encrypt('your key',$encrypted); 

//The RC4 Class
 class RC4Crypt {
    function encrypt ($pwd, $data){
        $key[] = '';
        $box[] = '';
        $pwd_length = strlen($pwd);
        $data_length = strlen($data);
        for ($i = 0; $i < 256; $i++){
            $key[$i] = ord($pwd[$i % $pwd_length]);
            $box[$i] = $i;
        }
        for ($j = $i = 0; $i < 256; $i++){
            $j = ($j + $box[$i] + $key[$i]) % 256;
            $tmp = $box[$i];
            $box[$i] = $box[$j];
            $box[$j] = $tmp;
        }
        $cipher = '';
        for ($a = $j = $i = 0; $i < $data_length; $i++){
            $a = ($a + 1) % 256;
            $j = ($j + $box[$a]) % 256;
            $tmp = $box[$a];
            $box[$a] = $box[$j];
            $box[$j] = $tmp;
            $k = $box[(($box[$a] + $box[$j]) % 256)];
            $cipher .= chr(ord($data[$i]) ^ $k);
        }
        return ($cipher);
    }
    function decrypt ($pwd, $data){
        return RC4Crypt::encrypt($pwd, ($data));
    }
}
```