# Preparing a multi-dimensional array for an ExtJS tree control

Tags: php, javascript, extjs

please dont close this question as repeated one..........
I am new to php.
I am developing one tree grid in extjs.were i need to display field in tree format.so for front end i need to send the encoded data.
I want 2 functions for encoding and decoding a string variable,multidimensional array,variables with a set of delimiters.
For example if i am having an array.........

```
array(
array( "task" => "rose",
"duration" => 1.25,
"user" => 15
),
array( "task" => "daisy",
"duration" => 0.75,
"user" => 25,
),
array( "task" => "orchid",
"duration" => 1.15,
"user" => 7
),
array( "task" => "sunflower",
"duration" => 1.50,
"user" => 70
)

);
```

i want to encode all the array fields or single field as..........

```
array(
array( "task" => "rose",
"duration" => 1.25,
"user" => 15
),
array( "task" => "daisy",
"duration" => 0.75,
"user" => 25$sbaa,
),
array( "task" => "orchid",
"duration" => 1.15,
"user" => 7$!ass,
),
array( "task" => "sunflower",
"duration" => 1.50,
"user" => 70$!abc
)

);
```

So like this only i need to encode string,variables with delimiters.........
later all the encoded values to be decoded before its taken back to back end.....for this i have to use this plugin..........
encode.class.php...........

```
<?php

/*-------------------------
Author: Jonathan Pulice
Date: July 26th, 2005
Name: JPEncodeClass v1
Desc: Encoder and decoder using patterns.
-------------------------*/

class Protector
{

var $Pattern = "";
var $PatternFlip = "";
var $ToEncode = "";
var $ToDecode = "";
var $Decoded = "";
var $Encoded = "";
var $Bug = false;
var $DecodePattern = "";

function Debug($on = true)
{
$this->Bug = $on;
}

function Encode()
{


$ar = explode(":", $this->Pattern);
$enc = $this->ToEncode;

if ($this->Bug) echo "<!-- BEGIN ENCODING -->\n";

foreach ($ar as $num => $ltr)
{
switch ($ltr)
{
case "E":
$enc = base64_encode($enc);
break;
case "D":
$enc = base64_decode($enc);
break;
case "R":
$enc = strrev($enc);
break;
case "I":
$enc = $this->InvertCase($enc);
break;
}
if ($this->Bug) echo "<!-- {$ltr}: {$enc} -->\n";
}

if ($this->Bug) echo "<!-------------------->\n\n";

@$this->Encoded = ($enc == $this->Str) ? "<font color='red'>No Encoding/Decoding Pattern Detected!</font>" : $enc;

return $this->Encoded;

}

function Decode()
{

$pattern = ($this->DecodePattern != "") ? $this->DecodePattern : $this->Pattern;

//Reverse the pattern
$this->PatternFlip($pattern);

//make into an array
$ar = explode(":", $this->PatternFlip);

$t = ($this->Encoded == "") ? $this->ToDecode : $this->Encoded;

if ($this->Bug) echo "<!-- BEGIN DECODING -->\n";

foreach ($ar as $num => $ltr)
{
switch ($ltr)
{
case "E":
$t = base64_encode($t);
break;
case "D":
$t = base64_decode($t);
break;
case "R":
$t = strrev($t);
break;
case "I":
$t = $this->InvertCase($t);
break;
}
if ($this->Bug) echo "<!-- {$ltr}: {$t} -->\n";
}

if ($this->Bug) echo "<!-------------------->\n\n";

$this->Decoded = ($t == $this->Encoded) ? "<font color='red'>No Encoding/Decoding Pattern Detected!</font>" : $t;

return $this->Decoded;

}

function MakePattern($len = 10)
{
//possible letters
// E - Base64 Encode
// R - Reverse String
// I - Inverse Case
$poss = array('E','R', 'I');

//generate a string
for ( $i = 0 ; $i < $len ; $i++ )
{
$tmp[] = $poss[ rand(0,2) ];
}

//echo $str. "<br>";
//fix useless pattern section RR II
$str = implode(":", $tmp);

//fix
$str = str_replace( 'R:R:R:R:R:R' , 'R:E:R:E:R:E' , $str );
$str = str_replace( 'R:R:R:R:R' , 'R:E:R:E:R' , $str );
$str = str_replace( 'R:R:R:R' , 'R:E:R:E' , $str );
$str = str_replace( 'R:R:R' , 'R:E:R' , $str );
$str = str_replace( 'R:R' , 'R:E' , $str );

//fix
$str = str_replace( 'I:I:I:I:I:I' , 'I:E:I:E:I:E' , $str );
$str = str_replace( 'I:I:I:I:I' , 'I:E:I:E:I' , $str );
$str = str_replace( 'I:I:I:I' , 'I:E:I:E' , $str );
$str = str_replace( 'I:I:I' , 'I:E:I' , $str );
$str = str_replace( 'I:I' , 'I:E' , $str );

//string is good, set as pattern
$this->Pattern = $str;
return $this->Pattern; //if we need it

}

function PatternFlip($pattern)
{
//reverse the pattern
$str = strrev($pattern);

$ar = explode(":", $str);

foreach ($ar as $num => $ltr)
{
switch ($ltr)
{
case "E":
$tmp[] = "D";
break;
case "D":
$tmp[] = "E";
break;
case "R":
$tmp[] = "R";
break;
case "I":
$tmp[] = "I";
break;
}

}

$rev = implode(":", $tmp);

$this->PatternFlip = $rev;

return $this->PatternFlip;
}

// This is my custom Case Invertor!
// if you would like to use this in a script, please credit it to me, thank you
function InvertCase($str)
{
//Do initial conversion
$new = strtoupper( $str );

//spluit into arrays
$s = str_split( $str );
$n = str_split( $new );

//now we step through each letter, and if its the same as before, we swap it out
for ($i = 0; $i < count($s); $i++)
{
if ( $s[$i] === $n[$i] ) //SWAP THE LETTER
{
//ge the letter
$num = ord( $n[$i] );

//see if the ord is in the alpha ranges ( 65 - 90 | 97 - 122 )
if ( ( $num >= 65 AND $num <= 90 ) OR ( $num >= 97 AND $num <= 122 ) )
{
if ($num < 97 ) { $num = $num + 32; }
else { $num = $num - 32; }

$newchr = chr($num);

$n[$i] = $newchr;
}
}
}

//join the new string back together
$newstr = implode("", $n);

return $newstr;

}
```

}

?>
............
from this plugin i need to use encode and decode functions for my functions.........
if anyone can help me on this.......it will be very much useful for me.......

Comment: Xref: [Numerous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322129/php-array-encoding-and-decodingneed-a-function-for-encoding-and-decoding-string) [previous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348975/how-to-encode-and-decode-multidimensional-arrays-in-php) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390998/functions-for-encoding-and-decoding-strings-and-arrays-in-php).  **Thank you for actually telling us *what you are trying to accomplish* this time around!**

Comment: Now, @0001, can you tell us why you "have to" use this horrible, backwards, silly encoding scheme?  If you're working with ExtJS, then why aren't you using JSON, *the* number one best format for exchanging data with Javascript?

Comment: I've updated the title and tagging of this question to hopefully attract some *useful* attention.

Comment: i am strictly ordered to use that horrible plugin only............:-( ....ya after encoding the data i need to send json format to frontend of that encoded data......

Comment: I'm hesitant to ask, but is there code in the ExtJS tree control to handle this encoding?  If not, how do they expect you to actually work with the data once it's there?  You'd either need to re-implement the decoder in Javascript or make *another* call to PHP just for the decode, and that's *really silly*.

Comment: no everything encoding and decoding is done at back end php file only.........will pass only json encoded and decoded data to extjs tree control..........decoding function is used when we want do edit or delete operation on the tree nodes......sorry for my bad english.....

Comment: is there anyone to help me............

Comment: Charles r u there??? please reply me with any solution......i am in need of that

Comment: @0001, sorry, I'm in the US and needed to actually sleep.  I'll come back to this in a bit with an answer discussing a few options.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use json_encode? Just do

```
$str=json_encode($array);
```

Then, send the data, and at the other end do

```
$array=json_decode($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's break down the problem.

You have an array.  Each element in the array is a hash.  One (or more) of the values in that hash *has* to be encoded using that horrible abomination of a library.  But the library can't process arrays.

We'll have to process the array ourselves.

`<rant>`
Before we begin, I'd just like to again express how horribly that "Protector" code is designed.  It's written for PHP4 and is effectively spaghetti code wrapped in a class.  It mis-uses properties, almost as if the user had some sort of mis-remembering about how *Java's* instance variables work and somehow thought it would be appropriate or sane to use PHP in the same way.  If the author of the code doesn't look back on that revolting chunk of bytes now with utter disdain, something is severely wrong with him.

`</rant>`

I'm going to base my knowledge of this class on [this copy of it](http://www.phpkode.com/source/s/jpencodeclass/jpencodeclass/encode.class.php), as the one you've provided is formatted even worse than the original.

First, let's create a list of inner array keys that we need to encode.

```
$keys_to_encode = array( 'user' );
```

Your example encoding lists only the `user` key as encodable.  If you need to encode others, just add more elements to that array.

Now, let's prepare our "Protector."  It seems to want you to either specify a pattern, or use the `MakePattern` method to have it create one.  *We're going to manually-specify one because `MakePattern` can come up with effectively useless combinations.*

```
$stupid = new Protector();
$stupid->Pattern = 'E:I:E:R:D:I:E';
```

This will base64-encode, flip the case, base64 again, reverse it, un-base64, flip the case, and then re-base64.  Be aware that PHP's base64 decoder "correctly" ignores bad padding and unexpected characters, which is the only reason the base64-reverse-unbase64 thing will work.  The resulting string will look like gibberish to people that don't know what base64 looks like, and un-base64 to gibberish for people that to know what base64 looks like.

If you need to encode the values in a certain way, you'd do so by just changing the pattern.  It's important that you either hard-code the pattern or store it somewhere with the data, because without it, you'll have a hard time doing the decode.  (I mean, it can be done *by hand*, but you don't want to have to do that.)  I expect that your boss is going to give you specific instructions on the pattern, given that you don't have an option in using this utter failure at a class.

Now it's time to process our data.  Let's pretend that `$in` contains your original array.

```
$out = array();
foreach($in as $k => $target) {
    foreach($keys_to_encode as $target_key) {
        $stupid->ToEncode = $target[ $target_key ];
        $target[ $target_key ] = $stupid->Encode();
    }
    $out[$k] = $target;
}
```

This loops through the array of hashes, then inside each hash, only the keys we want to encode are encoded.  The encoded hash is placed in a new array, `$out`.  This is what you'd pass to your tree widget.

Decoding is just as easy.  You've stated that your goal is letting users edit certain data in the tree widget, and you seem to want to protect the underlying keys.  This tells me that you *probably* only need to deal with one of the hashes at a time.  Therefore, I'm going to write this decode sample using only one value, `$whatever`.

```
$stupidest = new Protector();
$stupidest->Pattern = 'E:I:E:R:D:I:E'; // SAME PATTERN!
$stupidest->ToDecode = $whatever;
$decoded = $stupidest->Decode();
```

Again, it's *critical* that you use the same decode pattern here.

As for the actual interaction with the tree widget, you're on your own there.  I know only enough about ExtJS to know that it exists and that the GUI creators for it are really fun to play with.