# how to convert string to array in php after encoding?

Tags: php, arrays, string

Hi i am having original array as.............

```
array( 
       array( "task" => "rose", 
              "duration" => 1.25,
              "user" => 15 
            ),
       array( "task" => "daisy", 
              "duration" => 0.75,
              "user" => 25,
            ),
       array( "task" => "orchid", 
              "duration" => 1.15,
              "user" => 7 
            ),
           array( "task" => "sunflower", 
              "duration" => 1.50,
              "user" => 70 
            )

     );
```

after encoding it become string as............

```
0=task=rose&39avfy;
duration=1.25&39avfy;
user=15&39avfy;
&1=task=daisy&39avfy;
duration=0.75&39avfy;
user=25&39avfy;
&2=task=orchid&39avfy;
duration=1.15&39avfy;
user=7&39avfy;
&3=task=sunflower&39avfy;
duration=1.5&39avfy;
user=70&39avfy;
```

now i want the original array back from this string.......
so please if anyone knows then help me...........

Comment: What is the purpose of this operation? Editing specific elements in that array? Because you can do it directly on the array...

Comment: How did you transfrom your array into the string?

Comment: please check my post..here i gave how i did all this stuff....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401471/preparing-a-multi-dimensional-array-for-an-extjs-tree-control

Comment: One answer at the post in the link you gave suggested that you use json_encode() and json_decode() functions. Have you tried using those?

Comment: no that is final output......before that only i need to do encode

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert PHP array string into an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684553/convert-php-array-string-into-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

I'm repeating my answer from your other question:

Why don't you use json_encode? Just do

```
$str=json_encode($array);
```

Then, send the data, and at the other end do

```
$array=json_decode($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using [strtok](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) or [explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function, with parameters as `&39avfy;`. Then use the `explode` function again with parameters "=".

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to pass an array to POST or GET data, if yes, why not using serialize ?